set 128 bit uuid to the advertisement (esp32)
How to set a 128-bit advertising UUID service on ESP 32 (using ESP-IDF)?. Here is required UUID BB930001-3CE1-4720-A753-28C0159DC777
i've tried to set 128-bit adv uuid as gatt_svr_svc_uuid template and made required changes in fileds.
Also, i can't see device in NRF CONNECT app, and sometimes i only see default 1800 and etc. services
static const ble_uuid128_t gatt_svr_svc_uuid =
BLE_UUID128_INIT(0x2d, 0x71, 0xa2, 0x59, 0xb4, 0x58, 0xc8, 0x12,
                 0x99, 0x99, 0x43, 0x95, 0x12, 0x2f, 0x46, 0x59);

static uint8_t gatt_svr_chr_val;
static uint16_t gatt_svr_chr_val_handle;
static const ble_uuid128_t gatt_svr_chr_uuid =
BLE_UUID128_INIT(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11,
                 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33);

static uint8_t gatt_svr_dsc_val;
static const ble_uuid128_t gatt_svr_dsc_uuid =
BLE_UUID128_INIT(0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12,
                 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x23, 0x34, 0x34, 0x34, 0x34);

static int
gatt_svc_access(uint16_t conn_handle, uint16_t attr_handle,
            struct ble_gatt_access_ctxt *ctxt,
            void *arg);

static const struct ble_gatt_svc_def gatt_svr_svcs[] = {
{
    /*** Service ***/
    .type = BLE_GATT_SVC_TYPE_PRIMARY,
    .uuid = &gatt_svr_svc_uuid.u,
    .characteristics = (struct ble_gatt_chr_def[])
    { {
            /*** This characteristic can be subscribed to by writing 0x00 and 0x01 to the CCCD ***/
            .uuid = &gatt_svr_chr_uuid.u,
            .access_cb = gatt_svc_access,
#if CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ENCRYPTION
            .flags = BLE_GATT_CHR_F_READ | BLE_GATT_CHR_F_WRITE |
            BLE_GATT_CHR_F_READ_ENC | BLE_GATT_CHR_F_WRITE_ENC |
            BLE_GATT_CHR_F_NOTIFY | BLE_GATT_CHR_F_INDICATE,
#else
            .flags = BLE_GATT_CHR_F_READ | BLE_GATT_CHR_F_WRITE | BLE_GATT_CHR_F_NOTIFY |     BLE_GATT_CHR_F_INDICATE,
#endif
            .val_handle = &gatt_svr_chr_val_handle,
            .descriptors = (struct ble_gatt_dsc_def[])
            { {
                  .uuid = &gatt_svr_dsc_uuid.u,
#if CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ENCRYPTION
                  .att_flags = BLE_ATT_F_READ | BLE_ATT_F_READ_ENC,
#else
                  .att_flags = BLE_ATT_F_READ,
#endif
                  .access_cb = gatt_svc_access,
                }, {
                  0, /* No more descriptors in this characteristic */
                }
            },
        }, {
            0, /* No more characteristics in this service. */
        }
    },
},

{
    0, /* No more services. */
},
};

static int
gatt_svr_write(struct os_mbuf *om, uint16_t min_len, uint16_t max_len,
           void *dst, uint16_t *len)
{
uint16_t om_len;
int rc;

om_len = OS_MBUF_PKTLEN(om);
if (om_len < min_len || om_len > max_len) {
    return BLE_ATT_ERR_INVALID_ATTR_VALUE_LEN;
}

rc = ble_hs_mbuf_to_flat(om, dst, max_len, len);
if (rc != 0) {
    return BLE_ATT_ERR_UNLIKELY;
}

return 0;
}

static int
gatt_svc_access(uint16_t conn_handle, uint16_t attr_handle,
            struct ble_gatt_access_ctxt *ctxt, void *arg)
{
const ble_uuid_t *uuid;
int rc;

switch (ctxt->op) {
case BLE_GATT_ACCESS_OP_READ_CHR:
    if (conn_handle != BLE_HS_CONN_HANDLE_NONE) {
        MODLOG_DFLT(INFO, "Characteristic read; conn_handle=%d attr_handle=%d\n",
                    conn_handle, attr_handle);
    } else {
        MODLOG_DFLT(INFO, "Characteristic read by NimBLE stack; attr_handle=%d\n",
                    attr_handle);
    }
    uuid = ctxt->chr->uuid;
    if (attr_handle == gatt_svr_chr_val_handle) {
        rc = os_mbuf_append(ctxt->om,
                            &gatt_svr_chr_val,
                            sizeof(gatt_svr_chr_val));
        return rc == 0 ? 0 : BLE_ATT_ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RES;
    }
    goto unknown;

case BLE_GATT_ACCESS_OP_WRITE_CHR:
    if (conn_handle != BLE_HS_CONN_HANDLE_NONE) {
        MODLOG_DFLT(INFO, "Characteristic write; conn_handle=%d attr_handle=%d",
                    conn_handle, attr_handle);
    } else {
        MODLOG_DFLT(INFO, "Characteristic write by NimBLE stack; attr_handle=%d",
                    attr_handle);
    }
    uuid = ctxt->chr->uuid;
    if (attr_handle == gatt_svr_chr_val_handle) {
        rc = gatt_svr_write(ctxt->om,
                            sizeof(gatt_svr_chr_val),
                            sizeof(gatt_svr_chr_val),
                            &gatt_svr_chr_val, NULL);
        ble_gatts_chr_updated(attr_handle);
        MODLOG_DFLT(INFO, "Notification/Indication scheduled for "
                    "all subscribed peers.\n");
        return rc;
    }
    goto unknown;

case BLE_GATT_ACCESS_OP_READ_DSC:
    if (conn_handle != BLE_HS_CONN_HANDLE_NONE) {
        MODLOG_DFLT(INFO, "Descriptor read; conn_handle=%d attr_handle=%d\n",
                    conn_handle, attr_handle);
    } else {
        MODLOG_DFLT(INFO, "Descriptor read by NimBLE stack; attr_handle=%d\n",
                    attr_handle);
    }
    uuid = ctxt->dsc->uuid;
    if (ble_uuid_cmp(uuid, &gatt_svr_dsc_uuid.u) == 0) {
        rc = os_mbuf_append(ctxt->om,
                            &gatt_svr_dsc_val,
                            sizeof(gatt_svr_chr_val));
        return rc == 0 ? 0 : BLE_ATT_ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RES;
    }
    goto unknown;

case BLE_GATT_ACCESS_OP_WRITE_DSC:
    goto unknown;

default:
    goto unknown;
}

unknown:
assert(0);
return BLE_ATT_ERR_UNLIKELY;
}

void
gatt_svr_register_cb(struct ble_gatt_register_ctxt *ctxt, void *arg)
{
char buf[BLE_UUID_STR_LEN];

switch (ctxt->op) {
case BLE_GATT_REGISTER_OP_SVC:
    MODLOG_DFLT(DEBUG, "registered service %s with handle=%d\n",
                ble_uuid_to_str(ctxt->svc.svc_def->uuid, buf),
                ctxt->svc.handle);
    break;

case BLE_GATT_REGISTER_OP_CHR:
    MODLOG_DFLT(DEBUG, "registering characteristic %s with "
                "def_handle=%d val_handle=%d\n",
                ble_uuid_to_str(ctxt->chr.chr_def->uuid, buf),
                ctxt->chr.def_handle,
                ctxt->chr.val_handle);
    break;

case BLE_GATT_REGISTER_OP_DSC:
    MODLOG_DFLT(DEBUG, "registering descriptor %s with handle=%d\n",
                ble_uuid_to_str(ctxt->dsc.dsc_def->uuid, buf),
                ctxt->dsc.handle);
    break;

default:
    assert(0);
    break;
}
}

int
gatt_svr_init(void)
{
int rc;

ble_svc_gap_init();
ble_svc_gatt_init();
ble_svc_ans_init();

rc = ble_gatts_count_cfg(gatt_svr_svcs);
if (rc != 0) {
    return rc;
}

rc = ble_gatts_add_svcs(gatt_svr_svcs);
if (rc != 0) {
    return rc;
}

/* Setting a value for the read-only descriptor */
gatt_svr_dsc_val = 0x99;

return 0;
}

